# Let $x_n := (I +n S)^{-1} f$ for all $n$. How to prove that $(x_n)$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $S :H \to H$ be a bounded linear operator such that $\langle Su, u \rangle \ge 0$ for all $u \in H$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693745/how-to-prove-that-i-t-s-is-surjective) the map $I + t S$ is bijective for all $t>0$. Here $I:H \to H$ is the identity map. Fix $f\in H$ and let $x_n := (I +n S)^{-1} f$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

I'm trying to prove that

> **Theorem** $(x_n)$ is convergent in $H$.

It suffices to prove that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Clearly,
$$
x_n+n Sx_n = f = x_m + m S x_m
\quad \forall m,n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Then I don't know how to move forward.

> Could you elaborate how to prove above theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $x\in \ker S.$ Then $(I+nS)x=x,$ hence $x=(I+nS)^{-1}x.$ For $0\neq x\in (\ker S)^\perp$ we have $Sx\neq 0$ and
$${\|(I+nS)x\|\over \|x\|}\ge n{\|Sx\|\over \|x\|}-1\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty\quad (*)$$
Let $x\in {\rm Im}\,S.$ Then $x=Sv $ for some $v.$
We have
$$ y_n=(I+nS)^{-1}x=S(I+nS)^{-1}v$$ Thus $y_n\in {\rm Im}\,S\subset (\ker S)^\perp$ and $(I+nS)y_n=Sv=x.$ The formula $(*)$ implies $\|y_n\|\underset{n}{\to}0.$ By continuity we obtain $$\|(I+nS)^{-1}x\|\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0,\quad x\in \overline{{\rm Im}\,S}=(\ker S)^\perp$$
Summarizing, the sequence $(I+nS)^{-1}$ tends strongly (i.e. pointwise) to the orthogonal projection onto $\ker S.$

**Remark** We have used the property $\ker S=({\rm Im}\,S)^\perp.$ The latter space is equal $\ker (S^T),$ so it suffices to show that $\ker (S^T)=\ker S.$ The proof is in the spoiler.

> We have $$\langle (S+S^T)x,x\rangle =2\langle Sx,x\rangle \ge 0$$  Assume $Sx=0.$ Then $$\langle (S+S^T)x,x\rangle=0$$ As $S+S^T$ is positive self adjoint we get $(S+S^T)x=0.$ Hence $S^Tx=0.$

Comment: We have $y_n=(I+nS)^{-1}x=(I+nS)^{-1} (Sv) =(I+nS)^{-1} \circ S (v)$. Could you explain how $y_n=S(I+nS)^{-1}v$ and $y_n\in {\rm Im}\,S$?

Comment: The operators $I+nS$ and $S$ commute. Therefore $(I+nS)^{-1}$ and $S$ commute.

Comment: Could you confirm that ${\rm Im}\,S\subset (\ker S)^\perp$ follows from the positivity of $S$?

Comment: I have taken for granted that $N(S)=R(S)^\perp$ from you previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693745/how-to-prove-that-i-t-s-is-surjective) If this holds then $R(S)\subset N(S)^\perp.$

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!

Comment: Just in case I have included a proof of $N(S)=R(S)^\perp$ in the spoiler.